# VBA to use the excel formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using the formula to compare data between 2 columns on 2 different sheets and get the value required when the data matches. How do I use the formula in the VBA. Please suggest.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH("Index*"&Sheet1!A2&"*",Sheet2!B:B,0)*1),"No Match")
```

Comment: I suggest you record a macro of you adding the formula and that will generate your code.

Comment: How do you want to use it in VBA?  You need to offer the code where you want to use it... It's very easy to add that in.

Comment: Just use Sheet1.Range("A1").Formula = ... (of course you have to change the sheet and range to fit your needs...

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a worksheet formula within VBA as follows:

```
Sub qwerty()
    MsgBox [=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH("Index*"&Sheet1!A2&"*",Sheet2!B:B,0)*1),"No Match")]
End Sub
```

You could also make a string out of the formula and use `Evaluate()`